# Fourier series of a point charge in a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I would like some help understanding what this problem is asking and how to tackle it since I have not seen something like this before. Here it goes:

> A point charge $q$ is on the $y=0$ plane at the point $(x_0,0,z_0)$. Expand $q(x,z)$ as a Fourier Series. $\sum_{n,l}q_{n,l}\sin{(n\pi x/a)}\sin{(n\pi z/c)}$

I am not even sure if I understand the question correctly. What is $q(x,z)$ even mean? the position of the charge? When they give me that sum, are they telling me it is a sine series? or do I need to figure that myself. Here's what I know:

If $f(x)$ is a function integrable on a interval of length $P$, which we take as the period of the Fourier series, then the series expansion of $f(x)$ is

$$
f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi x}{P}\right) + b_n\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi x}{P}\right) \right),
$$

and by using the orthogonality properties of sine and cosine over a period, I can figure out the Fourier coefficients, in theory. But it seems I don't know much about $q(x,z)$, or am I overlooking something? Finally, how do I deal with the Fourier series of a function of two variables? I thought something like one expansion as above for each dimension, but does that even make sense? when solving the Laplace equation using separation of variables, I can see how the double sum arises, but how do I do that here to begin with?

Context: This is for a course on Electromagnetism using Griffiths' book "Introduction to electrodynamics". The problem is not from the book.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Perhaps it means for you to express the charge density as a Fourier series.

Comment: Maybe $q(x,z)$ is the electrostatic potential?

Comment: I think it would actually make sense if it is asking for the charge distribution since I can write that as $\rho(x,z) = q\delta(x-x_0)\delta(z-z_0)$ and will help me determine the Fourier Coefficients, I think.